# DateTime Error with TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc()

Tags: mysql, sql-server, date, datetime

In my current task, I am facing some mismatch in date time calculation. It is like user details management. User will have activation date(dd/mm/yyyy) and expiry date(dd/mm/yyyy). From UI the date details will be collected and it is saved in SQL DB. For example, If an user XYZ created today (19 May, 2016) then the user XYZ will have activation date as 19-05-2016 and expiry date is set as 25-05-2016 (it is based on user desire).

> User Name: XYZ
>
> Activation Date: 19-05-2016
>
> Expiry Date: 25-05-2016

So when trying to display the details in the site, the user details are retrieved from SQL DB, and the date time is converted to UTC time zone then details are passing to the site for user view. In DB the date is as it is, but while converting it using TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(), then the date value getting reduced by 1 (if the date is 19-05-2016 then it is converted as 28-05-2016)

```
select username, activationdate, expirydate from UserDetails where username = 'XYZ'
```

Result of the query is,

```
username | activationdate          |  expirydate
------------------------------------------------------------
XYZ      | 2016-05-19 00:00:00.000 | 2016-05-25 00:00:00.000
```

After converting to UTC,

```
ExpiryDate = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc((DateTime)user.expirydate);
ActivationDate = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc((DateTime)user.activationdate);
// after execution of these statements
// ExpiryDate = 2016-05-18 00:00:00.000
// ActivationDate = 2016-05-24 00:00:00.000
```

So after ConvertTimeToUtc() the actual activationdate 2016-05-19 00:00:00.000 converted as 2016-05-18 00:00:00.000 ans the expiry date 2016-05-25 00:00:00.000 is converted as 2016-05-24 00:00:00.000. I have referred a link saying that TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc() will [Convert the specified date and time to Coordinated Universal Time (UTC)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb381744(v=vs.110).aspx). I have also tried online conversion of current date and time to UTC in [google](https://www.google.co.in/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=current%20date%20to%20UTC), it converts the time to UTC but I don't see this much difference in date. My confusion is why this UTC conversion is reducing the date value by one complete date ? OR where the thing is getting wrong ?

Any suggestion on this would be helpful.

Comment: You are saving in the UTC equivalent of the users time zone time. When you pull the time back to the client are converting back from UTC to the users time zone info?

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is your storing the date as 2016-05-19 00:00:00.000.Try to get the exact time including minutes seconds that is time stamp from user.I believe you are from IST when it is night 12'o clock means they are behind us that's why you are seeing the previous date.Let me know if you have any queries.

Comment: With the exact time also that one day difference is still there :(

Comment: Am not familiar in C#.Instead of coding in C# you can try to convert in sql SELECT CONVERT_TZ( "columnname", @@session.time_zone, '+00:00' ) and then bind to C#